# jQuery.validator.addClassRules ... is there a Decimal or IsNumeric option?

Tags: jquery, validation

This does not allow decimals:

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
            FilterInput: {
                required: true,
                digits: true
            }
        });
```

Surely there must be a way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

The answer is: number

```
jQuery.validator.addClassRules({
            FilterInput: {
                required: true,
                number: true
            }
        });
```